# jquery ajax - upload filed or image not getting cleared after jquery ajax success

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax for form submission.
on the sucess of ajax i am clearing all fields
all fields getting cleared but only image is not cleared.

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
        error: function(xhr) {
            //status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
            $('#msgDisp span').text('Insertion FAILED!');
            $('#model-overlay').css('display', 'block');
            $("#msgDisp").css('display','block').fadeOut(3000);
            $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.errors == 0) {
                $('.required').each(function () {
                    $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).val('');
                    $('#blah').hide();
                });
                $('#msgDisp span').text('Details updated Successfully');
                $("#msgDisp").css('display','block').fadeOut(3000);
                $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is the code for that?

Comment: `$("#YourFormID")[0].reset();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clearing the image and all the fields we have to use reset form function.
**document.getElementById("formId").reset();** or
**document.querySelector("formSelector").reset();**

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
        error: function(xhr) {
            //status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
            $('#msgDisp span').text('Insertion FAILED!');
            $('#model-overlay').css('display', 'block');
            $("#msgDisp").css('display','block').fadeOut(3000);
            $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.errors == 0) {
                $('.required').each(function () {
                    $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).val('');
                    document.getElementById("uploadForm").reset();
                    $('#blah').hide();
                });
                $('#msgDisp span').text('Details updated Successfully');
                $("#msgDisp").css('display','block').fadeOut(3000);
                $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code you are missing `.required` class or `id` of your html filre input element, please make sure.

Following are ways to clear file input.

By `val('')`

```
$('#inputId').val('');
```

By `clone()` method

```
$inputId = $('#inputId');
$inputId.replaceWith( $inputId = $inputId.clone( true ) );
```

Reset full form By

```
$("#inputId").closest('form').trigger('reset');
```

Comment: @VaibhavS I think there is another issue in your `html`, can you please provide your html?

Comment: @VaibhavS I think you are missing `.required` class or `id` of your file input, please make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try restting form like `$('form')[0].reset();`

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
        error: function(xhr) {
            //status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
            $('#msgDisp span').text('Insertion FAILED!');
            $('#model-overlay').css('display', 'block');
            $("#msgDisp").css('display','block').fadeOut(3000);
            $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.errors == 0) {
                $('form')[0].reset();
                $('#msgDisp span').text('Details updated Successfully');
                $("#msgDisp").css('display','block').fadeOut(3000);
                $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using ajax for submission right so you can use either formData for submission and reset the entire form as $("#your_form_id").reset(); or you can simply reset type text or type file fields by simply setting an empty value $("#id_of_your_file_element").val("");